# Prevent wsgi from modifying 401 responses

Tags: python, pylons, wsgi

If I have the following pylons controller:

```
def challange(self):
    response.status = '401 Unauthorized'
    return 'You are not logged in.'
```

I would expect to see 'You are not logged in.' But I see :

> ## Unauthorized
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser does not understand how to supply the credentials required.
>
> ---
>
> WSGI Server

I have disabled the pylons error middleware. But the wsig server seems to be modifying the response. How do I stop this?

Comment: It is not Pylons middleware message, it's Paste's

Comment: which Pylons version you are using? On 1.0b1 it shows the text returned by action.

Comment: I figured that it was not pylons that was changing it.
I'm using 0.9.7,  so I'll try 1.0b1

Comment: Which WSGI server are you using?  The question is probably unanswerable without that information.